# Getting data from XMLHttpRequest responseText

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

i'm using ajax to get some data which i want to use after ajax is done. however i can't manipulate the response 
here's my code

```
function testAjax() {           
        direc = "controller.php";
        return $.ajax({url: direc});            
        }           
        var obj = testAjax(); 
        console.log(obj);           
        console.log(obj.responseText);
```

console.log(obj) returns this :

```
 XMLHttpRequest { readyState=1,  timeout=0,  withCredentials=false,  more...}
```

response

```
"[{"CLICREDIT_Cod":"1002","CLICREDIT_Credit":"2000","CLICREDIT_FlagEstad":"1"}]"
```

responseText

```
"[{"CLICREDIT_Cod":"1002","CLICREDIT_Credit":"2000","CLICREDIT_FlagEstad":"1"}]"
```

console.log(obj.responseText) returns this :

```
(an empty string)
```

is there a way to manipulate that data? i've tried some stuff like JSON.parse but nothing seems to work, any help would be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: You might want to add the jquery tag, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ajax is async you have to use then:

```
promise.then( doneCallback, failCallback )
```

---

```
function testAjax() {
  direc = "controller.php";
  return $.ajax({
    url: direc
  });
}
var obj = testAjax();

obj.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
}, function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
  alert(xhr.status);
  alert(thrownError);
});
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, could you explain a little how that works? this is new to me

Comment: if you want to fully understand the code, you have study how async task handled in javaScript, jquery promises is a way, $.ajax returns a promise: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wrangle-async-tasks-with-jquery-promises--net-24135

Answer (score 1):

This is asynchronous, you need to use the `.done()` function. Take a look at the sample [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback function after `success`. Browser does not wait for a response and continue with code. so when browser get result, callback function will hit.

```
$.ajax({url: direc, success: doSmth});
function doSmth(data){
//do something with data
}
```

Comment: i want to use the data out of the ajax i've tried using a variable like var variable; $.ajax({url: direc, success: doSmth});
function doSmth(data){
variable = data;
} then i realized it doesn't work that way

Answer (score 0):

use success() to get response of requested page

```
 var responseText={};
 $.ajax({url: 'controller.php',
    type:"POST",
    success: function(data)
   {
        responseText= data;

    }});
```